# Salesforce Email Reply BCCs

Tags: email, email-template, servicecloud

My client is looking to remove the auto BCC on Case Reply emails:
[image: Like this]

I can do this by updating the EmailPreferencesAutoBcc field on the user record for the existing Users but how do I prevent this from getting set to true in the future? Is there a setting someplace in the Org to control this or do I need to create my own flow to stop this?

Thank you!

Comment: you'll have to create your own scheduled flow/apex or do this on the update trigger for user to continually make sure no user records have this setting enabled. It's a per-user setting. You can't actually set this to false on the insert of the user ([see here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333030&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)) which is why I suggest doing it on update or doing it within a scheduled context.